# Force Origin in fiddler without breakpoints

Tags: ajax, cors, fetch, fiddler, response-headers

I have created a rule in fiddler that sets the response header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*".
but when perfoming a js Ajax request from the chrome console, the browser still throws a "Access-Allow-Origin..." error.

It seems that the only way to bypass the error, is by applying the fiddler rule and fiddler Breakpoint After the response arrives.

Is there any way to do this without turning on the automatic breakpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, add the rule under "OnPeekAtResponseHeaders" instead of under OnBeforeResponse.

just add :

```
  oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
  oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```